# Why does using an arrow function give the updated version of the state in React in comparison to calling the function normally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, arrow-functions

Take the following react code

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {state1: true, state2: false, state3: "hello"}
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)

    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({state1: false, state2: true, state3: "goodbye"}, console.log(this.state))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick = {this.onClick}></button>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I use `console.log` in the callback for `setState`, I have to click the button twice in React in order for the console to display the correct version of state.

However, if write `this.setState({state1: false, state2: true, state3: "goodbye"}, () => console.log(this.state))` instead, adding an arrow function, clicking the button once outputs the correct version of the state in the console. Why is that? Why does an arrow function output different behaviour in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `console.log(this.state)` is first evaluated, and the resulting value is passed into `setState`.

In other words, this

```
this.setState({state1: false, state2: true, state3: "goodbye"}, console.log(this.state))
```

can be re-written to the following without changing its behavior:

```
let consoleLogResult = console.log(this.state)
this.setState({state1: false, state2: true, state3: "goodbye"}, consoleLogResult)
```

**You log the current state before you set it.**

Now, `console.log` always *returns* `undefined`, so `consoleLogResult` above will always be `undefined`. It behaves like you never passed a callback 'function' at all.

---

If you instead pass `() => console.log(this.state)`, it evaluates to a function, which is called by React *after* the state transition was executed.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second one argument for this.setState()  is callback that is called when state is updated.
console.log() doesn't return function, it's called at the same time when you call this.setState()

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you're doing this:

```
this.setState({state1: false, state2: true, state3: "goodbye"}, console.log(this.state))
```

That is not passing a function as the second parameter, it is evaluating the function `console.log` with the current value of `this.state` and passing its returned result (which for `console.log` is always undefined) as the second parameter. But if you use the second parameter of `setState`, React expects it to be a function, not undefined, so it won't actually have any callback to run when the state updates.

In your second example, you are actually passing a new function as the parameter, and once that function is called (as a callback, by React, when the new state has been set), *that function* calls `console.log`; by then, the state is set and so it logs the new value.